# iOS and mutable IBOutletCollections

Tags: objective-c, ios, iboutletcollection

I have the property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSMutableArray *allOpposition;
```

which is wired up in IB to a bunch of subviews and synthesized. Later I have:

```
- (void)willRemoveSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
  [[self allOpposition] removeObject:subview]; // Crash occurs here.
  [super willRemoveSubview:subview];
}
```

When the time comes to remove the view representing an opposing entity, I get the following error message:

`-[__NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88211c0`

The object is not `nil` and is contained in the collection. How come my array is immutable?

Remark: Quite possibly Apple requires each object in the collection to be of type `UIView`, in this case. If the array were fully mutable conceivably I could add foreign types. I haven't found much documentation here so this is speculation on my part.

Remark: I don't see the value of allowing a mutable array to be passed in if the returned array is ultimately immutable. Why not just accept immutable arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have declared the property as a mutable array, but I'm pretty sure that when your nib is loaded an immutable array will be assigned to it.

Override the synthesised setter for `allOpposition` (I'm assuming you're using xcode4.4 or later and ARC):

```
-(void)setAllOpposition:(NSMutableArray*)allOpposition
{
    _allOpposition = [allOpposition mutableCopy];
}
```

You may also be able to achieve this by changing the property declaration from `strong` to `copy`, but that's a guess.

Comment: Thanks, it certainly works and is probably the best option here.