# Adding more objects to a IBOutletCollection declared as an NSMutableArray causes exception

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, unrecognized-selector, iboutletcollection

I'm using an iPad 6.1 Simulator and I don't understand why when I try to add another object to an IBOutletCollection it causes an error of

> __NSArrayI addObject: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I set up a test project and proved it in the following:

```
ViewController.m

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSMutableArray *collection;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *collection2;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    // Test 1 - Pass
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject:label];

    // Test 2 - Pass
    _collection2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.collection2 addObject:label];



    // Test 3 - Fails   
    [self.collection addObject:label];

}

@end
```

Just before test 3, if I do a `lldb:p self.collection` it returns
`(NSMutableArray *) $0 = 0x071817b0 @"3 objects"`

The three objects it is referring to are those I connected via IB.
Somehow I think XCode 4.3.2 is lying and the collection must be an NSArray.

I've also tried `[_collection addObject:label]` with the same result.

Any thoughts on the subject would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12577440/581994.  Override the setter for `collection` to create a mutable copy.

Answer (score 2):

If we look into your error message,

**__NSArrayI addObject: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

What is __NSArrayI?

**__NSArrayI** is a code-word for an immutable array (NSArray)

That means, the error tries to tell you that you are calling the addObject: method of NSArray. NSArray does not have an addObject: method.

Something has gone wrong.
**self.collection** has become a NSArray, not NSMutable array. may be you are assigning an NSArray to self.collection or you have reinitialized the self.collection as an NSArray.

### Please double check your code.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behavior that you get, except when I add a breakpoint, I get,

```
$0 = 0x07199520 <__NSArrayI 0x7199520>
```

It does seem like the NSMutableArray declaration doesn't work, even though the documentation says that you can use IBOutletCollection in front of NSArray or NSMutableArray. I found that I could fix the problem with the following line in viewDidLoad:

```
self.collection = [self.collection mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)setCollection:(NSMutableArray*)collectionParm {
    _collection = [collectionParm mutableCopy];
}
```